Do I need another expansion tank for the water heater if I have one on the boiler system?
I think I do, but would like some confirmation in my specific case before spending the time and money installing one. Here are some facts:

I have 60 gal gas water heater, which almost always dribbles some water from the pressure relief valve after using a lot of hot water
I'm fairly certain we have high water pressure as is (city water, THERE IS a double check valve right after the meter)
We also have a boiler for home heat, which is connected to the cold supply with a Taco 3350-3 valve and expansion tank

I have looked at these questions which are similar, but not enough to make me confident in my conclusion:
Do I need a thermal expansion tank if I already have a pressure tank?
Do I need separate expansion tanks for my boiler and water heater?
From what I understand right now, the boiler system is protected with its expansion tank, but the taco valve would prevent it from helping with the potable water system. This would mean I would need another expansion tank on the cold side of the water heater. The more I think as I type this out, the more I think it is a silly question with an obvious answer, but I am still not 100% sure of the function of the taco valve, so confirmation would be greatly appreciated. I will attach some pictures for clarity, and I am happy to answer questions.
Thanks!



Your boiler runs a closed system.  The radiators, pipes, and boiler are separated from the world by the fill valve and pressure relief valve. Normally those are both closed.  The system must have an expansion tank and that tank only serves the closed system.
If you have a pressure reducer or check valve on your main water supply your water heater also needs an expansion tank.  If you have no such valve an expansion tank would do nothing as the pressure is defined by the supply.
A leaky hot water pressure relief valve may be a sign that you do need one or it may just be dirty or faulty.  Note that a pressure relief valve that is leaking because of the lack of an expansion tank may also as a result, develop an inherent leak caused by continuous deposit of calcium in the mechanism. In other words, it may not have been faulty but it may keep leaking after you install an expansion tank and may need to be replaced.

What you say about the boiler makes sense to me, but I am confused by "If you have a pressure reducer... and an expansion tank would do nothing". As I said I'm not positive there is one, but assuming there is a check valve on my water supply, I would think that draining the tank of hot water, replacing with cold, and then heating that cold water with nowhere for it to go (cant go back to city supply) would cause a spike in pressure, and an expansion tank would solve exactly that. Did you mean unless it has a check valve, or do pressure reducers commonly act as one?

Just double checked and found a stand alone check valve tucked away by the meter. With that in mind, I believe your answer indicates I SHOULD have an expansion tank. If you could just clarify your language around "if you have a pressure reducer" (assuming you meant pressure reducer or check valve) I will accept this answer. Thanks!

Your understanding is correct.  I made the answer clearer.

@DouglasB -- note that while the fill valve on your boiler keeps it from communicating with your water system under normal conditions, you may still need a backflow prevention device on the fill line to the boiler as well

Thanks @ThreePhaseEel, I don't believe there is one for the boiler specifically, so I will have to add that to the list.
